# Finite State Machine vs. another technique for UI Testing in C#

Tags: c#, testing, user-interface, bots

I am writing a UI-Testing/Bot program. The program simulates the behavior of a person. FSM is used: the current window is represented by state, Click on a windows button by a transition. The program analyzes the current window and performs the next transition. The problem here. It may arise an unexpected window with information. One solution would be to define a transition for each state ,that describes the unexpected window.

Before starting the program you need to select the desired behavior. So for FSM I should use another transition in depending on selected behavior. 
Q1: Can you use an OOP method for this problem?

I have tried to write the following implementation. Each state is represented by a class. In each state class an overloaded method is invoked, that decides what the next state should be chosen. The language that I choose is C#.

Q2:What programming methods can I use as an alternative to the FSM?

Answer (score 0):

1) For changing behavior/transition logic you can implement the [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern), here's [an example in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/346873/Understanding-and-Implementing-the-Strategy-Patter)

2) Can you provide more details on "The program simulates the behavior of a person"? What do you want to accomplish? Navigate all the buttons? Arrive to some end point?

Comment: The program can simulate the behavior of someone who wants to achieve a specific end goal. This goal may be to have similar duties to perform for half an hour. The algorithm performs useful work to relieve users. By the way UI is also tested.

Comment: Thank you for  the nice idea. I follow your example of design pattern. "Strategy" pattern requires that "context" with correct "ConcreteStrategy" class is initialized. Do I need an additional class or function for each state? A "factory" that initialized the "ConcreteStrategy"? The programming effort is not small.

Comment: Yes, as you stated "_In each state class an overloaded method is invoked, that decides what the next state should be chosen._", you have to implement a class for each strategy for every state you need, for example `StateAStrategy1`, `StateAStrategy2` and forth.
The Factory is used as a way to input the chosen strategy and get the correct state classes as output: `StateFactory.GetStates(StrategyC)` should return the state classes that implement the "C" strategy. Note that for some states, all strategies can use the same class, and som other states can have different classes.

Comment: For your goals, I think a FSM-type of program using Strategy pattern is a good solution. If you think the programming effort is too much, what about something simpler, like a script? You can make a little bunch of scripts, each one that performs one single goal.